# Dice roll combinations in Monopoly with doubles, using total combinations and sums of dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

So in Monopoly, when doubles are rolled with a pair of dice, one can roll again to reach a new sum. For example, 5 can be reached with (1,4), (4,1), (2,3), (3,2) or with doubles - (1,1) and (1,2) or (1,1) and (2,1). The probability of getting a 5 is thus $\frac {1}{36}+\frac {1}{36}+\frac {1}{36}+\frac {1}{36}+(\frac {1}{36})^2+(\frac {1}{36})^2 = 0.11265 $. One method I tried to use to model this was by taking the total number of ways to get 5 divided by the total number of possible sum combinations in monopoly. Including doubles, I found that there are $((36\times 6)+30)\times 6)+30 = 1506$ possible sums (I can try to explain this later if anyone would like), and of this there are 6 ways to get 5. But $\frac {6}{1506} = 0.003984 $ and not $0.11265$. Is my fundamental logic in approaching this wrong? I would appreciate any help, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's been decades since I played monopoly, but isn't there a rule limiting the number of consecutive doubles you can roll?  I want to say after three straight doubles, your turn ends.

Comment: Yes indeed, that rule exists :). Three doubles puts you in jail. This is why my sum ends with 3 possible doubles.

Comment: But the six sums aren't equally likely.  Your example shows this.  Four of them have probability $1/36$ and two have probability $1/36^2.$

Comment: I see what you're getting at, I suppose this assumes those probabilities are equal. Is there a way to model these sums using this approach? Other than taking a case-by-case basis, is there no mathematical way to prove these probabilities using combinations?

Comment: You can try to organize the calculations efficiently certainly, but I can't see any way to get the answers with a formula.

Comment: Damn, thanks for clarifying this for me :)

Comment: Have you tried considering the partitions of the sums, and then multiplying with the respective probability? The number $5$ can be partitioned in $6$ ways, for example $5=2+2+1$ or $5 = 3+2$. However you can't consider all partitions, you'd have to discard those that have the term $1$ in them (you can't roll a $1$ with a pair of dice), and those partitions with more than $3$ terms (because of the max numbers of turns). But, as @saulspatz said, I don't think there is a way to turn this method into a formula because the number of partitions varies and we only consider some of them.

Comment: I was actually thinking of partitions! But I thought the very definition of a partition is the sum of all integers to a number, not just a fixed amount. Forgive me, but could you elaborate on what you meant by multiplying the partitions with the probabilities? I could try this once I understand it, thanks!